# Login with htmlunit and javascript

Tags: java, javascript, htmlunit

I have one quick question about htmlUnit, I hope that somebody can help me. How to login into this site http://ld.opendata.cz:8897/sparql-auth ?? I have no problems with static pages but I don't like javascript popup here, what to do?
I use Java HtmlUnit. Thanks so much

Comment: (Java and JavaScript tags in the same question? This is Madness!)

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right, this is not javascript, my fault :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "basic http authentication" mechanism (google for it if you don't know what is it). It is not javascript. HtmlUnit provides something for it, start looking here: http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/DefaultCredentialsProvider.html